# What should I do with this exeption Python Sympy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

This is my code:

```
import sympy
question = '''(6i+7+9+6)+(9i-0i+4)-(3i+9*1)'''
result = sympy.simplify(question)
print(result)
```

And exeption is:

```
sympy.core.sympify.SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse '(6i+7+9+6)+(9i-0i+4)-(3i+9*1)'' failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: '(6j+7+9+6)+(9j-0j+4)-(3j+9*1)' works.  In python `2j` is an imaginary number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based of the following resource on simplification: [Sympy Simplification](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html)

Try changing your `question` variable to the following:

`question = (6*i+7+9+6)+(9*i-0*i+4)-(3*i+9*1)`

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Compiler writes question = (6i+7+9+6)+(9i-0i+4)-(3i+9*1) SyntaxError: invalid syntax and targets on i

Comment: @omgmegic Make sure you input **exactly** what I've provided in my answer. You cannot do `6i` in python as the compiler does not recognize this is what is commonly done in math. You must do `6*i`.

Comment: `simplify` will work with a string, by first passing it through `sympify`.  It's `sympify` that's having problems with the "2i".  The error actually says that!

Comment: @hpaulj Very interesting! Based on the link I found there were no examples using strings. I'll update the answer accordingly. Thanks!